# Issue with graphing subjects and items growth curve model vs subjects-only in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I have been having trouble graphing growth curve model results that have been calculated over both subjects and items (both included as random effects), while models calculated over a dataset that is averaged over items, so that subjects are the only random effect, seems to work fine. I cannot seem to figure out why this would be or how to fix it.

[Graph of Subject Only Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7wei.png)

[Graph of Subjects and Items Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvI5d.png)

[Summary DF Subj Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnNmk.png)

[Summary DF Subj Only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST70q.png)

```
> dput(head(new.df.subjitems, 20))
structure(list(Item.No = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
Subject_No = c(330, 322, 141, 330, 330, 
330, 137, 330, 330, 330, 137, 330, 137, 330, 330, 137, 137, 330, 
137, 141), 
Bin.No = c(35, 17, 19, 44, 42, 34, 31, 23, 36, 32, 
33, 28, 23, 33, 37, 7, 4, 30, 28, 31), 
TargetFix = c(1, 1, 1, 
0, 0.02, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
Condition.E = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("First", "Second", "Max Entropy, Unrelated", 
"Third", "Fourth", "Max Entropy, Competitive"), class = "factor"), 


    ot1 = c(-0.00489995957550024, 0.220498180897511, -0.171498585142509, 
    0.142098827689507, 0.210698261746511, -0.20089834259551, 
    -0.0538995553305028, -0.151898746840508, -0.112699070236506, 
    -0.230298100048512, 0.0146998787265008, -0.161698665991508, 
    -0.151898746840508, 0.0146998787265008, -0.122498989387506, 
    0.0538995553305028, 0.181298504293509, -0.0440996361795023, 
    -0.161698665991508, -0.0538995553305028), 
ot2 = c(-0.158018948215706, 
    0.226392531578272, 0.0744512352170155, 0.00151941296361255, 
    0.192965446378795, 0.161057774142931, -0.135227753761518, 
    0.024310607417801, -0.0577376926172773, 0.26133902974136, 
    -0.156499535252094, 0.0486212148356019, 0.024310607417801, 
    -0.156499535252094, -0.0395047370539266, -0.135227753761518, 
    0.101800668562042, -0.142824818579581, 0.0486212148356019, 
    -0.135227753761518), 
ot3 = c(0.0112384799617412, 0.177762495548696, 
    0.0718614343707494, -0.14311051566666, 0.113069194230467, 
    -0.05612035827049, 0.113717568074414, 0.12506411034348, 0.167352493276442, 
    -0.250560469916257, -0.0335353360396831, 0.101434485808536, 
    0.12506411034348, -0.0335353360396831, 0.16389449944206, 
    -0.113717568074414, -0.035984748339037, 0.0957432042894495, 
    0.101434485808536, 0.113717568074414), 
ot4 = c(0.158779933129858, 
    0.0903598052498265, -0.175158477576023, -0.166766788637329, 
    -0.00086703192354873, -0.0706803112875428, 0.0864589810947309, 
    -0.178854426512889, -0.0950686572656207, 0.205524262921174, 
    0.153690832709029, -0.182263550144233, -0.178854426512889, 
    0.153690832709029, -0.123325047363878, 0.0864589810947308, 
    -0.15558879673071, 0.109609880754701, -0.182263550144233, 
    0.0864589810947309)), 
.Names = c("Item.No", "Subject_No", 
"Bin.No", "TargetFix", "Condition.E", "ot1", "ot2", "ot3", "ot4"
), row.names = c(1L, 5L, 8L, 22L, 29L, 59L, 61L, 74L, 78L, 86L, 
90L, 98L, 101L, 111L, 115L, 120L, 126L, 133L, 140L, 145L), class = "data.frame")


> dput(head(df.subjonly, 20))
structure(list(Subject_No = c(103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 
103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103
), 
Bin.No = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), 
TargetFix = c(0.16667, 0.16667, 0.16667, 
0.16667, 0.32667, 0.39, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.62667, 0.59, 0.66667, 
0.66667, 0.76667, 0.76333, 0.66667, 0.40667, 0.33333, 0.48333
), 
Condition.E = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("First", 
"Second", "Max Entropy, Unrelated", "NaN, Unrelated", "Third", 
"Fourth", "Max Entropy, Competitive", "NaN, Competitive", "Low Entropy, NaN", 
"High Entropy, NaN", "Max Entropy, NaN", "NaN, NaN"), class = "factor"), 

ot1 = c(-0.240098019199512, -0.230298100048512, -0.220498180897511, 
    -0.210698261746511, -0.20089834259551, -0.19109842344451, 
    -0.181298504293509, -0.171498585142509, -0.161698665991508, 
    -0.151898746840508, -0.142098827689507, -0.132298908538507, 
    -0.122498989387506, -0.112699070236506, -0.102899151085505, 
    -0.0930992319345048, -0.0832993127835043, -0.0734993936325038, 
    -0.0636994744815033, -0.0538995553305028), 
ot2 = c(0.297804940868062, 
    0.26133902974136, 0.226392531578271, 0.192965446378795, 0.161057774142931, 
    0.13066951487068, 0.101800668562042, 0.0744512352170154, 
    0.0486212148356019, 0.0243106074178009, 0.0015194129636125, 
    -0.0197523685269634, -0.0395047370539266, -0.0577376926172774, 
    -0.0744512352170155, -0.0896453648531411, -0.103320081525654, 
    -0.115475385234555, -0.126111275979843, -0.135227753761518
    ), 
ot3 = c(-0.331823325024233, -0.250560469916256, -0.177762495548696, 
    -0.113069194230468, -0.0561203582704902, -0.00655577997768254, 
    0.0359847483390369, 0.0718614343707493, 0.101434485808536, 
    0.12506411034348, 0.14311051566666, 0.15593390946916, 0.16389449944206, 
    0.167352493276442, 0.166668098663387, 0.162201523293977, 
    0.154312974859294, 0.143362661050417, 0.12971078955843, 0.113717568074414
    ), 
ot4 = c(0.347265133901292, 0.205524262921176, 0.0903598052498273, 
    -0.000867031923547791, -0.0706803112875423, -0.121489365408538, 
    -0.15558879673071, -0.175158477576023, -0.182263550144233, 
    -0.178854426512889, -0.16676678863733, -0.147721588350685, 
    -0.123325047363878, -0.0950686572656211, -0.0643291795224186, 
    -0.0323686454785664, -0.000334356356151326, 0.0307411167449481, 
    0.0599399328470624, 0.0864589810947308)), .Names = c("Subject_No", 
"Bin.No", "TargetFix", "Condition.E", "ot1", "ot2", "ot3", "ot4"
), row.names = 3:22, class = "data.frame")
> 

# create 4th-order polynormial in the range of Bin.no
t <- poly ((unique(new.df.subjitems$Bin.No)), 4)
# create variables ot1, ot2, ot3, ot4 corresponding to the orthogonal 
polynomial time terms and populate their values
# with the Bin.No-appropriate orthogonal polynomial values:
new.df.subjitems[,paste("ot", 1:4, sep="")] <- t[new.df.subjitems$Bin.No, 1:4]
Model.subjitems.2 <- lmer(TargetFix ~ (ot1+ot2+ot3+ot4)*Condition.E + 
(1+ot1+ot2+ot3+ot4|Subject_No) +(1+ot1+ot2+ot3+ot4|Item.No),
                    control = lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"), 
data=new.df.subjitems, REML=F)

# create 4th-order polynormial in the range of Bin.no
t <- poly ((unique(df.subjonly$Bin.No)), 4)
# create variables ot1, ot2, ot3, ot4 corresponding to the orthogonal 
polynomial time terms and populate their values
# with the Bin.No-appropriate orthogonal polynomial values:
df.subjonly[,paste("ot", 1:4, sep="")] <- t[df.subjonly$Bin.No, 1:4]
Model.subj.2 <- lmer(TargetFix ~ (ot1+ot2+ot3+ot4)*Condition.E + 
(1+ot1+ot2+ot3+ot4|Subject_No),
               control = lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"), data=df.subjonly, 
REML=F)

# Graph Subject Items
ggplot(data=new.df.subjitems, aes(Bin.No, TargetFix, color=Condition.E, 
lty=Condition.E, shape=Condition.E)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se,geom="ribbon",linetype=0,alpha=0.25) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se,geom="point",size=1,alpha=0.40) 
+stat_summary(aes(y=fitted(Model.subjitems.2)),
fun.y=mean,geom="line",size=2.0,alpha=0.9) +
  theme_bw(base_size=10) +
  labs(y="Fixation Proportion", x="Bins") +
  ggtitle("Subjects and Items, Target Fixations") +
  theme(text=element_text(color = "black", size=20, family = "Georgia")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size=10, family = "Georgia")) 
+
  scale_color_viridis(begin=0, end = .8, discrete=TRUE) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(3,2,16,7)) + #16,3,2
  theme(legend.key.width=unit(4,"line")) +
  ggsave("Testing_SubjectItems_v3.png",width=10,height=5)

# Graph Subject Only
ggplot(data=df.subjonly, aes(Bin.No, TargetFix, color=Condition.E, 
lty=Condition.E, shape=Condition.E)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se,geom="ribbon",linetype=0,alpha=0.25) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se,geom="point",size=1,alpha=0.40) +
stat_summary(aes(y=fitted(Model.subj.2)),
fun.y=mean,geom="line",size=2.0,alpha=0.9) +
  theme_bw(base_size=10) +
  labs(y="Fixation Proportion", x="Bins") +
  ggtitle("Subj Only, Target Fixations") +
  theme(text=element_text(color = "black", size=20, family = "Georgia")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size=10, family = "Georgia")) 
+
  scale_color_viridis(begin=0, end = .8, discrete=TRUE) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(3,2,16,7)) + #16,3,2
  theme(legend.key.width=unit(4,"line")) +
  ggsave("Testing_SubjectOnly_v3.png",width=10,height=5)
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(new.df.subjitems)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(new.df.subjitems, 20))`.

Comment: I have now done so, I think. Thank you.